# how a password is sent in HTTP protocol?

Tags: http, tornado, packet-sniffers

am sorry for this dumb question, but am using [RawCap](http://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap) to detect packets sent and received to learn what is sent in HTTP, and the page is a simple application made using Tornado and MongoDB, when i capture packets, i dont find the password in any packet sent.

Why? i dont use any encrypted protocole like HTTPS, it's a simple HTTP and cant see the password.

here is the file:
[The result](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-Iu7VFIRkh4Wk1aZzROMXdvQ0E/edit)

as you can see, Mongodb answers the value of the database, and brings the password as it is saved (PBKDF2), but cant see the one sent from the first time.

Comment: Which password exactly are you talking about? The HTTP basic authtication password?

Comment: D'oh. There are 1000 ways to login. Which way are you talking about? The HTTP basic authentication way? If you have no idea what to answer, please tell step by step how exactly you've configured the login.

Comment: yes, only a POST that sends a request to compare the email and the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you don't see the password because the page is using [HTTP basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) which encodes the username and password using [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). Look for a string like:

> Authorization: SomeRealmName QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Basic authentication, then the password is base 64 encoded. *ENCODED* not encrypted. Look for something like this in your packets: `Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=`